# Why my generic input component refreshes even when I do not click on the given component - ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angular

For some reason, when I have on my site opened 4/5 angular forms suddenly there is a gigantic decline in application performance.

Although I click on one component, all active inputs refresh anyway.

Is there anyone who can help me?

[image]

```
<generic-input-new [props]...></generic-input-new>
```

This is a simple component generated with ng g c, has ngOnChanges in it and accepts some inputs and has its own function

Comment: please share your components (parent/child) code

Comment: `ngOnChanges` is a devil -- try not to use it